# How to get response data from a redirect url using HttpWebRequest

Tags: c#, web-crawler, httpwebrequest

I'm spidering some data from Weibo, but when I get data from `https://weibo.com/ajax/profile/getImageWall?uid=6596153448&sinceid=0&has_album=true`, it returns a HTML string like

```
        <html>
        <head>
        <title>����ͨ��֤</title>
        <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; url=&#39;https://weibo.com/ajax/profile/getImageWall?uid=6596153448&sinceid=0&has_album=true&display=0&retcode=6102&#39;"/>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=GBK" />
        </head>
        <body bgcolor="#ffffff" text="#000000" link="#0000cc" vlink="#551a8b" alink="#ff0000">
        <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
        location.replace("https://weibo.com/ajax/profile/getImageWall?uid=6596153448&sinceid=0&has_album=true&display=0&retcode=6102");
        </script>
        </body>
        </html>
```

I noticed the HTML has a code `location.replace`. While I put the **original** URL in Chrome browser, it return a json like:

```
{"data":{"album_list":[{"pic_title":"自拍","containerid":"2318266596153448_-_pc_profile_album_-_photo_-_camera_-_1_-_%E8%87%AA%E6%8B%8D","pic":"https://wx1.sinaimg.cn/webp720/007coMPKly1ggbize7velj30u011j4qp.jpg"},{"pic_title":"地点","containerid":"2318266596153448_-_pc_profile_album_-_place_index","pic":"https://wx1.sinaimg.cn/webp720/007coMPKly1gygh591i2fj36ht7nb4qx.jpg"},{"pic_title":"原创","containerid":"2318266596153448_-_pc_profile_album_-_photo_-_camera_-_0_-_%E5%8E%9F%E5%88%9B","pic":"https://wx4.sinaimg.cn/webp720/007coMPKgy1hl9jy1oai1j32pg1sz7wj.jpg"},{"pic_title":"头像","containerid":"2318266596153448_-_pc_profile_album_-_photo_-_avatar_-_4259929979524585_-_%E5%A4%B4%E5%83%8F","pic":"https://wx1.sinaimg.cn/webp720/007coMPKly8hdnhynhunjj30go0go3yv.jpg"}],"album_since_id":0,"since_id":"4983950777909567_4983152500801576|1034:4982881450393669_20231228_-1","list":[{"pid":"007coMPKgy1hlgq3xod6yj34772d2x6t","mid":"4986199213348783","is_paid":false,"timeline_month":"01","timeline_year":"","object_id":"1042018:cd004793270ea3c1ccf34bb0b1e350ea","type":"pic"},{"pid":"007coMPKgy1hlgq47lakyj35902yb7wl","mid":"4986199213348783","is_paid":false,"timeline_month":"01","timeline_year":"","object_id":"1042018:62a874fda42b5e71dfc23072171eca1d","type":"pic"},{"pid":"007coMPKgy1hlgq4gf0bmj34772d2u13","mid":"4986199213348783","is_paid":false,"timeline_month":"01","timeline_year":"","object_id":"1042018:c2d7d16559b39b6fe837bc56ff23f76e","type":"pic"},{"pid":"007coMPKgy1hlgq4i7n4oj333z1r04qs","mid":"4986199213348783","is_paid":false,"timeline_month":"","timeline_year":"","object_id":"1042018:f8b0a33f4eebb68a0b6e8017c84ef7a1","type":"pic"},{"pid":"007coMPKgy1hlgcjn040jj30zk172dhj","mid":"4986080585583161","is_paid":false,"timeline_month":"","timeline_year":"","object_id":"1042018:6763914e838da276d0fb4effec830678","type":"pic"},{"pid":"007coMPKgy1hlgcjmzghyj31720zk0uu","mid":"4986080585583161","is_paid":false,"timeline_month":"","timeline_year":"","object_id":"1042018:dc6c415c2f5f885acbc2f97d1bfdb389","type":"pic"},{"pid":"007coMPKgy1hlgcjmx5i9j30sg1wvacu","mid":"4986080585583161","is_paid":false,"timeline_month":"","timeline_year":"","object_id":"1042018:83c5d96772500a2efc8a6270f6caf3cf","type":"pic"},{"pid":"007coMPKgy1hlgcjmx4lgj30zk172ac6","mid":"4986080585583161","is_paid":false,"timeline_month":"","timeline_year":"","object_id":"1042018:51f24986a3ea8a5e626768838aa1e8df","type":"pic"},{"pid":"007coMPKgy1hlgcjn0kyqj31ne0zk42r","mid":"4986080585583161","is_paid":false,"timeline_month":"","timeline_year":"","object_id":"1042018:0146316b2fb317469f83f42f7ea354b5","type":"pic"},{"pid":"007coMPKgy1hlgcjmx6taj31kw0zwju3","mid":"4986080585583161","is_paid":false,"timeline_month":"","timeline_year":"","object_id":"1042018:789415a67b539eb8accddf7c1fadd04b","type":"pic"},{"pid":"007coMPKgy1hlgcjng278j31cc0zk0yz","mid":"4986080585583161","is_paid":false,"timeline_month":"","timeline_year":"","object_id":"1042018:53d1d19e9a880802e1f8af116c559823","type":"pic"},{"pid":"007coMPKgy1hlgcjn3tluj30sg1ww0x3","mid":"4986080585583161","is_paid":false,"timeline_month":"","timeline_year":"","object_id":"1042018:c4c33567bb3e3876fb3e0052d9504c77","type":"pic"},{"pid":"007coMPKgy1hlgcjmx3j6j31720zk420","mid":"4986080585583161","is_paid":false,"timeline_month":"","timeline_year":"","object_id":"1042018:956c807a40bd04f773863569b7d97629","type":"pic"},{"pid":"007coMPKgy1hlgcjmwluqj30sg1azq57","mid":"4986080585583161","is_paid":false,"timeline_month":"","timeline_year":"","object_id":"1042018:9ff470f426b0bc3726257149b29f2fa9","type":"pic"},{"pid":"007coMPKgy1hlgcjmxx7lj31kw11xtbp","mid":"4986080585583161","is_paid":false,"timeline_month":"","timeline_year":"","object_id":"1042018:19ceab539f8cb085402bcfcffd73ff66","type":"pic"},{"pid":"007coMPKgy1hlf2r792puj35ir7drb2a","mid":"4985682256991154","is_paid":false,"timeline_month":"","timeline_year":"","object_id":"1042018:676555ff82e8879c1b5558ec013db063","type":"pic"},{"pid":"007coMPKgy1hlf2r9an2ij35ir7dsb2a","mid":"4985682256991154","is_paid":false,"timeline_month":"","timeline_year":"","object_id":"1042018:10d3f87cceff34661044990364d1e04c","type":"pic"},{"pid":"007coMPKgy1hlf2r7pf8yj35ir7dskjm","mid":"4985682256991154","is_paid":false,"timeline_month":"","timeline_year":"","object_id":"1042018:a706a95df02613d24ca754813f55d21f","type":"pic"},{"pid":"007coMPKgy1hlf2r7vypwj35ir7drb2a","mid":"4985682256991154","is_paid":false,"timeline_month":"","timeline_year":"","object_id":"1042018:b0e16dc5c27c21beb44263f8947c5683","type":"pic"},{"pid":"007coMPKgy1hlf2r7zks4j35is7dskjm","mid":"4985682256991154","is_paid":false,"timeline_month":"","timeline_year":"","object_id":"1042018:73d8c0c3a7beef3c893007b3ef171c43","type":"pic"},{"pid":"007coMPKgy1hlf2r7bopej35ir7dskjm","mid":"4985682256991154","is_paid":false,"timeline_month":"","timeline_year":"","object_id":"1042018:9ebbc80fb23f502741dbd569c1ab522e","type":"pic"},{"pid":"007coMPKgy1hl9jy1oai1j32pg1sz7wj","mid":"4983950735574935","is_paid":false,"timeline_month":"12","timeline_year":"2023","object_id":"1042018:98f7c79b5af33589374a67c00aacf7b8","type":"pic"},{"pid":"007coMPKgy1hl9jy1shwjj32pg1sz7wj","mid":"4983950735574935","is_paid":false,"timeline_month":"12","timeline_year":"2023","object_id":"1042018:2b972df446e7ab5f3d3955679643312b","type":"pic"},{"pid":"007coMPKgy1hl9jy0z7ohj347v59uqv7","mid":"4983950735574935","is_paid":false,"timeline_month":"12","timeline_year":"2023","object_id":"1042018:bafe8dcc10f47fe86827f6302473bb51","type":"pic"}]},"bottom_tips_visible":false,"bottom_tips_text":"","ok":1}
```

This json data is what I want.

So how to get the json data using HttpWebRequest?

my `HttpWebRequest` code is

```
var myHttpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
myHttpWebRequest.AllowAutoRedirect = true;
using (HttpWebResponse lxResponse = (HttpWebResponse)myHttpWebRequest.GetResponse())
{
    var stream = lxResponse.GetResponseStream();
    StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream);
    
    string text = reader.ReadToEnd();
}
```

Comment: Parse the HTML. The meta element looks like it has what you're looking for, it seems to have the same value as the JavaScript code.

Comment: @gunr2171 you mean I need to make a second request?

Comment: It's also worth noting that when you make a http call with your browser you send _a lot_ more extra information with the request than just the URL. Information such as the User Agent and cookies can affect how the server processes your request.

Comment: I know what you said. I parsed the html and made another request, then I got nothing.

Comment: You may want to reproduce the http call _exactly_ as your browser sends it. That includes all the headers it sends. Use your browser's network tools to inspect those calls. Also, consider using `HttpClient`, it's newer and not depreciated.

Comment: The website you are accessing has an API, you may want to use that instead. https://open.weibo.com/wiki/API

Comment: The JSON you see is generated by a script. The website also has a no-sniff policy (quite common). Its content is rendered in a WebBrowser, to avoid, well, people sniffing

Comment: @gunr2171 The official API has many restrictions and the app needs to be reviewed. So many Weibo spider do not use it.